# Reading a local file with Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to read in a file with Coffeescript. In the same folder where I enter into the `coffee` repo, I have a file named `hello.txt`.

```
coffee> fs = require 'fs'
coffee> x = fs.readFile "hello.txt"
undefined
coffee> x
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not passing a callback to `readFile` to actually read the file.  See [docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs.readFile) for further information. Generally, nodejs methods are asynchronous because of the asynchronous nature of the platform. For some of them there is a sync version. Indeed, you can read a file with the [readFileSync](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs.readFileSync) method.